# JSP not reflecting changes even after refreshing

Tags: jsp

I have added a new field in my JSP page, when I enter values in my field it perfectly saves into database, but after refreshing the page,  previously entered value is showing in added. I want this field to be empty to write any other value.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just want to know how to clear the session in jsp page after saving some data. You  have any idea about that.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].